# Install Adobe Air 2.6 Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS 64-bit

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit, adobe-air

Trying to install Adobe Air 2.6. After using `Sudo ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin`

I come up with the following error:

```
/tmp/air.Fic6yA/setup: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any help on this error would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
After trying to use the prepackaged files linked from Michael below, I get the following error:

```
(Reading database ... 374649 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack adobeair_2.6.0.19170-devolo1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking adobeair (1:2.6.0.19170-devolo1) over (1:2.6.0.19170-devolo1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of adobeair:
 adobeair depends on ia32-libs-gtk | devolo-ia32-libs; however:
  Package ia32-libs-gtk is not installed.
  Package devolo-ia32-libs is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package adobeair (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 adobeair
```

Comment: Ready made packages are available here: http://update.devolo.com/linux/apt/pool/main/a/adobeair/

Comment: I get the following: 'dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of adobeair:
 adobeair depends on ia32-libs-gtk | devolo-ia32-libs; however:
  Package ia32-libs-gtk is not installed.
  Package devolo-ia32-libs is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package adobeair (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 adobeair'

Answer (score 4):

You need to install these dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install libxt6:i386 libnspr4-0d:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libnss3-1d:i386 libnss-mdns:i386 libxml2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 libgnome-keyring0:i386 libxaw7
```

add make these links

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0
```

then install AdobeAir from the Adobe website

```
wget -O AdobeAIRInstaller.bin http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/lin/download/2.6/AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
chmod +x AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
sudo ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
```

then remove the links

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0
sudo rm /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0
```

[source](http://www.noobslab.com/2015/05/adobeair-is-now-available-for-ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, I did `sudo apt-get -f install` after attempting to install the prepackaged i386 version. This installed what I needed and I was able to use Adobe Air.